# How to add prefixes and suffixes to permutations in Python?

Tags: python, tuples, permutation

I'm trying to make a list of permutations prefixed by X and suffixed by Y.
Here are a few examples of what I've tried.

```
perm = permutations ([1,2,3], 3)

for i in list(perm):
    print ("Adam" + (i) + "Bob")
```

This brings back the error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str"

```
perm = permutations ([1,2,3], 3)

for i in list(perm):
    list (i)
    
def blink():
    print (("X" + (i) + "Y"))

blink()
```

This brings back the error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str"

Ideally the end result would print

```
X(1, 2, 3)Y
X(1, 3, 2)Y
X(2, 1, 3)Y
X(2, 3, 1)Y
X(3, 1, 2)Y
X(3, 2, 1)Y
```

Comment: Side-note: There is no reason to do `for i in list(perm):` here; `permutations` already returns an iterator, and `list`ifying it immediately before iterating just means you have to make a (potentially expensive, though not in this case) temporary `list` with all the `tuple`s when you only need one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Each element is a tuple, so convert it to a string with `str` first:

```py
for i in perm:
    print("Adam" + str(i) + "Bob")
```

Or, just use f-strings:

```py
for i in perm:
    print(f"Adam{i}Bob")
```

Comment: Alternative: `print("Adam", i, "Bob", sep="")` which lets `print` do the formatting without additional temporaries (the f-string variant is probably faster, and applies in more situations, just noting that in the specific case of `print` you don't need to format it to a single final string).